# write variable in Execute SQL Task

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2008

Based on few conditions I want to set a variable to true or false in Execute SQL Task.
This is my query

```
If  ?  <> 0
    BEGIN
    If CAST( ?  as DATE) <> (select MAX(cast(Date as DATE)) from <Table>)
        begin 
        set ? OUTPUT = 'True'
        end
END
```

I have created 3 parameter mapping. Removing the condition **set ? OUTPUT = 'True'** is fine. But when I add this statement I am getting error.

I am sure this would be syntax error but I am unable to figure it out.
I tried all these

```
set ? OUTPUT = 'True'
set ? = 'True'
    ? = 'True'
```

But nothing works and I end up with error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should select it instead, but I wouldn't use output as the name.

```
If  ?  <> 0
    BEGIN
    If CAST( ?  as DATE) <> (select MAX(cast(Date as DATE)) from <Table>)
        begin 
        select 'True' as Result
        end
END
```

Map the result of the execute sql statement to the target variable.